# excel vba to create json

Tags: excel, vba

I am not expert in vba. i have json format and i want to make this as dynamic where my sheet 1 has details with multiple rows and there are 7 cell value need to update in json format given below and paste in sheet2 column wise.

i want data to be replace where mention ****enterhere****

```
{
    "apiOperation": "CREATE_OR_UPDATE_MERCHANT",
merchant: {
        "cardMaskingFormat": "DISPLAY_6_4",
        "systemCapturedCardMaskingFormat": "DISPLAY_6_4",
        "categoryCode": "***enterhere***",    //this need to update from A2
        "goodsDescription": "***enterhere***",    //this need to update from b2
        "locale": "en_US",
        "name": "***enterhere***",     //this need to update from c2
        "timeZone": "Asia",
        "address": {
            "city": "***enterhere***",   //this need to update from d2
            "countryCode": "SAR",
            "postcode": "***enterhere***",   //this need to update from e2
"stateProvince": "***enterhere***",   //this need to update from f2
"street1": "***enterhere***"  //this need to update from g2
        },
service: [
ENABLE_DEVICE_PAYMENTS,
ENABLE_DECRYPT_APPLE_PAY,
ENABLE_DECRYPT_GOOGLE_PAY
        ],
acquirerLink: {
aaS2I01: {
                "terminalId": [
                    "aaa00056",
                    "aaa00057",
                    "aaa00058",
                    "aaa00059",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your json into a worksheet cell, and put placeholders (eg) `{{A2}}` you can replace with the cell values.  `json = wsJSON.Range("A1").Value: json = Replace(json, "{{A2}}", wsData.Range("A2").Value)` etc for the other values.

Comment: It is an invalid json string. eg. `merchant` should be `"merchant"`.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your json into a worksheet cell and use placeholders for the values to be added:

```json
{
    "apiOperation": "CREATE_OR_UPDATE_MERCHANT",
    merchant: {
        "cardMaskingFormat": "DISPLAY_6_4",
        "systemCapturedCardMaskingFormat": "DISPLAY_6_4",
        "categoryCode": "{{A2}}",   
        "goodsDescription": "{{B2}}",   
        "locale": "en_US",
        "name": "{{C2}}",    
        "timeZone": "Asia",
        "address": {
            "city": "{{D2}}",  
            "countryCode": "SAR",
            "postcode": "{{E2}}",  
            "stateProvince": "{{F2}}",  
            "street1": "{{G2}}" 
        },
       service: [ENABLE_DEVICE_PAYMENTS,ENABLE_DECRYPT_APPLE_PAY,ENABLE_DECRYPT_GOOGLE_PAY ],
       acquirerLink: {
         aaS2I01: { "terminalId": [ "aaa00056", "aaa00057", "aaa00058","aaa00059"]}
        }
    }
}
```

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, json As String, addr
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    json = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JSON").Range("A1").Value
    
    For Each addr In Array("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2")
        json = Replace(json, "{{" & addr & "}}", wsData.Range(addr).Value)
    
    Next addr
    
    Debug.Print json
End Sub
```